# Using enumerate() for operations between the elements of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumerate

Until now, given a list `L`, i was using `range(len(L))` to access its elements:

```
L = [4, 3, 5, 2, 7]

for i in range(len(L)):
    print(i, "-", L[i])
```

However, I've read that this approach is **not pythonic** and there's a function called `enumerate` that can do the work as well:

```
L = [4, 3, 5, 2, 7]

for i, n in enumerate(L):
    print(i, "-", n)
```

Now, allow me to propose a problem to show the trouble I've been experiencing with this approach:

> Given a list of integers `L`, transform the list so that every element `n` in the resulting list is the sum of the elements up to `n` in the initial list.

Using the first approach that would be:

```
L = [4, 3, 5, 2, 7]

for i in range(1, len(L)):
    L[i] = L[i] + L[i - 1]
```

When trying the second approach:

```
L = [4, 3, 5, 2, 1]

for i, n in enumerate(L): #It starts at element 0!
    L[i] = n + L[i - 1]
```

The **questions** that result from this problem are the following:

- How can I make enumerate start at element 1?
- Is the second approach actually worth it in this case?
- If the previous answer is "no", when is it worth it?

Comment: `enumerate(L, 1)`

Comment: I suggest using `itertools.accumulate` or `numpy.cumsum` for this task

Comment: this is what `reduce` used to be for..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis `reduce` only `return`s a single element, that's not what is desired here I think

Comment: @Chris_Rands although your answer solves this particular problem, I'm more interested in the questions that result from it, than in the actual problem.

Comment: @timgeb that results in an `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Answer (score 0):

Here's some solutions to this particular problem:

```
L = [4, 3, 5, 2, 7]

# Solution 0
print([sum(L[0:i + 1]) for i in range(len(L))])

# Solution 1
res = [0]
for i, n in enumerate(L):
    res.append(res[-1] + n)

print(res[1:])

# Solution 2
for i, n in enumerate(L[1:]):
    L[i + 1] = L[i + 1] + L[i]
print(L)
```

Comment: #0: Although small this solution is rather inefficient O(n²) instead of O(n) and doesn't use enumerate

Comment: #1: This solution creates a new list, which is not what the problem is asking

Comment: #2: What is the purpose of using n in this solution? That looks a lot like an equivalent of my first approach.

Answer (score -1):

Answering to `How can I make enumerate start at element 1`

You do that this way:

`L = [4, 3, 5, 2, 1]
for i, n in enumerate(L, start=1):`

Comment: OP does not want a new list. Leave it at `enumerate(mylist, start= 1)`

Comment: It was a pretty general example, unfortunately i can`t add it as a comment so i have to post it as answer.

Comment: Note that this solution throws an `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`